# Transpose Dynamic Row Into Column

Tags: sql, pivot, crosstab

This is my table. My stored procedure returns data in this format:

```
Product Name| Price
------------+---------------
 Apple      | 100
 Mango      | 150
 Banaba     | 70
```

But I want this data into this format below:

```
Apple | Mango | Banana
------+-------+---------
100   | 150   | 70
```

Comment: Google Pivot for the dbms you're using.

Comment: `GROUP BY` combined with `CASE`  is the usual way of doing pivots.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(case when a.product_name='Apple' then a.price else 0 end) Apple,
       max(case when a.product_name='Mango' then a.price else 0 end) Mango,
       max(case when a.product_name='Banana' then a.price else 0 end) Banana
  from (select * from demo) a
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.